# How do I package a Ruby application for Ubuntu, including its gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, deb

I have a command-line utility called [Maid](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid) that I currently distribute as [a RubyGem](https://rubygems.org/gems/maid).  I'd also like to distribute it as a `.deb` package [to make it easier for Ubuntu users to install](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid/issues/3-package-for-ubuntu).

Right now, Ubuntu users have to do quite a bit manually, especially for someone unfamiliar with Ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install rubygems
# Make sure `ruby` and `gem` are in `$PATH`
sudo gem install maid
maid version # example command
```

Ideally, I want a single command to install on a fresh Ubuntu installation:

```
sudo apt-get install maid
maid version # example command
```

The suite of `gem2deb` tools (`gem2tgz`, `dh-make-ruby`, etc.) are *almost* what I'm looking for.  **But** by default `gem2deb` doesn't package any of the gem dependencies that are required.  Maid is really simple and only depends on `thor` at runtime.  (**Edit:** as Maid has evolved, and now has more dependencies.)  But without that dependency, nothing works.

So, how do I package this Ruby application for Ubuntu and also include its gem dependencies?  Are there any other tools I could use or tutorials/examples I could follow?

Comment: I'm doing something similar, albeit not as complicated as maid. - https://launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/+archive/factero and https://github.com/jrgifford/ruby-debian-packaging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `apt-get` and `gem` are both dependency resolving, you can just make a meta package that depends on `ruby1.9.1` (which itself brings in Rubygems and everything else). Then in the post-install script, just do a `sudo gem1.9.1 install maid`.

I can't lay out the whole process of making a package here, but there are a lot of good tutorials on it around the web.

Comment: This seems less "pure" than I might like, but it also seems like the simplest solution.  Do you think that `gem install` should take a `--version` option?

Comment: Iirc, gem install has a -v option which does that.

Comment: np, thought I should fix it since I ran into it :)

Answer (score 3):

Using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) you can (among others) directly create debs from gems. The [wiki](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/ConvertingGems) has an extensive example. The gist of it is to call

```
cd /tmp
fpm -s gem -t deb maid
```

Comment: I came across `fpm` in my research.  It seems like a good project, but I'm not sure what to think about having to create/distribute packages like `rubygem-thor-0.14.6.amd64.deb`.  I've seen a number of Ruby projects embed their dependencies inside their `.deb` package for that reason, which also seems problematic.

Comment: A good compromise is to create your own apt repository and maintain that for your users. A good companion to fpm is [freight](https://github.com/rcrowley/freight/) which provides some easy to use helpers for maintaining such a repository. That said, you can also incorporate your dependencies with fpm, but would have to deal with potential package overlapping. Sadly, there's no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: I might do that with a PPA.  I might anticipate problems with dependencies if I ever want Maid to be in the Ubuntu Software Center, however.  Do you have a link for more information about "incorporating dependencies" with `fpm`?  Also, for what it's worth, I found that `fpm` didn't add `ruby` as a dependency in the control file.  Know anything further?

Comment: Well, you can simply package the full directory. You would have to specify the metadata yourself. You can also add/override the default metadata. See the wiki for more details.